# Drag and Crop Image like facebook in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to crop image for cover photo in my project and its functionality should similar like Facebook cover photo.

I only want drag image (set position) and crop it. After crop I want submit the form to save that image in database.

I search for many JS but not get succeed. My experience in Javascript (and jQuery) is between amateur and novice. Any help/suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Better try Cropper jQuery plugin.

http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: Example: Cropper with full crop box I need cropped image and need to send cropped image to API when clicked on SAVE button.